# Consuming WebService with PHP

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl

Please bear with me as this is my first post.
Currently helping my PHP developer to consume a webservice, but we have tried and spent days googling and trying some possible approach here at stackoverflow.

Is it possible if i just post the WSDL here.
We are getting error like "found unexpected element" /  "invalid namespace" / etc..

Hope to see sample PHP approach or atleast guide. Thank you so much

SoapUI Request:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <MINEInput userReference="MINE1234567" bankCode="12" channelID="?" branchCode="1234" accountNumber="123456789"/>
   </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

WSDL:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="MINE_Check_Inquiry" targetNamespace="urn:MINE_Check_Inquiry" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:stns2="ph.ots.Checkinquiry" xmlns:tns="urn:MINE_Check_Inquiry" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <wsdl:types>

      <xs:schema>
         <xs:complexType name="MINEInput">
            <xs:attribute name="userReference" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="bankCode" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="channelID" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="branchCode" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="accountNumber" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:element name="MINEInput" type="MINEInput"/>
      </xs:schema>

      <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="ph.ots.Checkinquiry">

      <xs:complexType name="OutputMessage">
            <xs:attribute name="data" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      </xs:complexType>

         <xs:element name="OutputMessage" type="stns2:OutputMessage"/>
      </xs:schema>

      </wsdl:types>

      <wsdl:message name="MINE_Check_Inquiry_sendTransaction_Request">
        <wsdl:part element="MINEInput" name="inputMessage"/>
      </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="MINE_Check_Inquiry_sendTransaction_Response">
      <wsdl:part element="stns2:OutputMessage" name="outputMessage"/>
   </wsdl:message>


   <wsdl:portType name="MINE_Check_Inquiry">
      <wsdl:documentation>[Add documentation here]</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:operation name="sendTransaction">
         <wsdl:input message="tns:MINE_Check_Inquiry_sendTransaction_Request"/>
         <wsdl:output message="tns:MINE_Check_Inquiry_sendTransaction_Response"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>


  <wsdl:binding name="MINE_Check_Inquiry_SOAPBinding" type="tns:MINE_Check_Inquiry">
      <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="sendTransaction">
         <soap:operation soapAction="urn:sendTransaction"/>
         <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>

   <wsdl:service name="MINE_Check_InquiryService">
      <wsdl:port binding="tns:MINE_Check_Inquiry_SOAPBinding" name="MINE_Check_Inquiry">
         <soap:address location="http://localhost:14172/MINE_Check_InquiryService/MINE_Check_Inquiry"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Appreciate all your response :)